# how to plot a pie chart?

Tags: python, pandas, pie-chart

I have data like:

> Machine_id    Cycling   Idle
>   81091001    41000000000 19000000000
>   81091001    40000000000 19000000000
>   81091001    41000000000 19000000000
>   81091001    41000000000 20000000000
>   81091001    41000000000 19000000000

Code for plotting Pie chart :

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(palette='Paired')

df = pd.read_csv('sample1.csv')

df = df.set_index('Machine_id')

for ind in df.index:
     fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
     fig.set_size_inches(5,5)
     df.iloc[ind].plot(kind='pie', ax=ax, autopct='%1.1f%%')
     ax.set_ylabel('')
     ax.set_xlabel('')
```

I am getting a error here like:

`IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds`

Then how a pie chart can be formed for  `Cycling` v/s `Idle` in pandas each `Machine_id` wise ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your problem solved:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set(palette='Paired')

df = pd.read_csv('sample1.csv')

#df = df.set_index('Machine_id')  comment this

for ind in df.index:
     fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
     fig.set_size_inches(5,5)
     df.iloc[ind].plot(kind='pie', ax=ax, autopct='%1.1f%%')
     ax.set_ylabel('')
     ax.set_xlabel('')
     fig.show()   #plot/show final results
```

**another way**, to consider individual chart with Cycling and Idle time per row. A Pie Chart for each line. (Maybe Pie Charts are not the best way to illustrate this but any way)

Ref.  https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html

```
import csv as csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

colors = ['r', 'g']

with open('sample1.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    i = 0

    for row in readCSV:
        if i == 0:
            activities = [row[1], row[2]]
            title = row[0]
        else:
            slices = [row[1], row[2]]
            plt.title("Machine ID: " + row[0])  #title is here UPDATED
            plt.pie(slices, labels=activities, colors=colors, startangle=90, autopct='%.1f%%')
            plt.show()

        i += 1
```

Comment: how to put whole column values of `Cycling` and `Idle` working ??

Comment: check again ;) I posted the solution

Comment: Yes, plot is great, but `Machine_id` as the title is not shown in the plot ?

Comment: @rahul I was checking on that issue but https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pie.html apparently there is no variable to add a title to the Pie but on this link we have a solution ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43275983/cant-add-title-to-pie-chart-matplotlib. I updated the code above!

Comment: Thanks a lot @oetoni