# Enlarge font of title on a pie chart Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart, font-size, title

I would like to enlarge this and edit the color of this please - plt.title("Groups %")

unable to enlarge this without receiving errors

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43275983/cant-add-title-to-pie-chart-matplotlib

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple example to show how one can do the followings for a pie chart:

- to change the figure size
- to change the font size of labels
- to change the font size of title

code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# data
cats = ['a', 'b', 'c']
vals = [0.35, 0.45, 0.20]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))   #<==== figure size
plt.title('Title', fontsize=20)   #<==== font size | Title
plt.pie(vals, labels=[f'{cat}: {val*100}%' for cat, val in zip(cats, vals)], textprops={'fontsize': 14}) #<==== font size | labels
plt.show()
```

output:

[image]